# Change shipping price programmatically in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to customize shipping price after customer select shipping method in checkout page. I have added a few lines of these code into `Magento_Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php`, but nothing has changed.

```
$totals = $this->cartTotalsRepository->get($cartId);
$totals->setShippingAmount($customPrice);
$totals->setBaseShippingAmount($customPrice);
```

Comment: which shipping method amount U try to change?

Comment: Store -> Configuration -> sales > Shiping methods already provide shipping amout

Comment: @Bhavik i want, for example adding up selected shipping amount.

Answer (score -1):

Check in to below Function

> Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectCarrierRates

Before `$this->getResult()->append($result);`

Set

```
$price = 10;
$result->setPrice ($price);
```